# Webservice em C# Leitura de Xml

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, soap

Boa Tarde, eu estou construindo uma WebService em C#, eu criei um método que lê um XML enviado como request e deveria devolver o nome do aluno... O probelma que estou enfrentando na verdade é quando eu tento realizar o teste utilizando o SoapUI, ao enviar o XML eu tenho um response vazio com o erro HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Gostaria de ajuda para resolver esse problema, pois não sei mais como resolver...

Segue o código das minhas classes utilizadas:

Método do meu webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
    public String CapturarDados(String Xml) {

        String retorno = "teste";

        try
        {
            LeitorXml p = new LeitorXml();

            retorno = p.LerXml(Xml);
        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {

            retorno = ex.Message;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe LeitorXml:

```
public class LeitorXml
{
    public String LerXml(String xml)
    {

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Alunos");

        string sNome = xnList[0]["nome"].InnerXml;

        String retorno = sNome;



        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
        file.WriteLine(sNome);

        file.Close();

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

XML de entrada :

```
  <Alunos>
           <nome>Caio</nome>
           <idade>21</idade>
           <email>teste@teste.com</email>
           <Endereco>
              <Rua>Av.Lins de Vasconcelos</Rua>
              <Bairro>Cambuci</Bairro>
              <Cidade>São Paulo</Cidade>
              <Estado>SP</Estado>
              <Cep>16520-005</Cep>
           </Endereco>
        </Alunos>
```

Utilizando o visual studio a resposta está OK.

[image: Utilizando o Visual Studio]

Mas ao utilizar o SoapUI esse é o problema apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teoricamente, o erro 400 BAD REQUEST diz que algo na sua requisição HTTP está incorreta, ou seja, talvez o formato do envelope que você está mandando esteja errado, dê uma boa verificada.

Comment: Pode ser até mesmo uma configuração do SoapUI.

Comment: O estranho é que se eu usar o método HelloWorld que já vem funciona no SoapUI, apenas esse método que criei não retorna nada e devolve esse erro.

Comment: Mas aí é uma requisição totalmente diferente, não tem como se comparar.

Comment: Já tentou usar o .NET Webservice Studio? Ele é bem mais leve e simples que o SOAPUi, testa ai com ele e me fala o que acontece. [link](https://webservicestudio.codeplex.com)